# regular expression for indian vehicle number in javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I need a regular expression in Javascript, as well as in PHP, for Indian vehicle NUMBER.

Here is the conditions list:

```
(x)(y)(z)(m)(a)(b)(c)
```

**1.** (x) contains only alphabets of length 2.
**2.** (y) may be `-` or  single space `' '`.
**3.** (z) contains only numbers of length 2.
**4.** (m) may be or `,` or  single space `' '`.
**5.** (a) must be one or two alphanumeric followed by an alpha.
**6.** (b) must be identical to (y).
**7.** (c) contains only numbers of length  4.

Here are some examples of valid vehicle numbers:

- RJ-14,NL-1234
- RJ-01,4M-5874
- RJ-07,14M-2345
- RJ 07,3M 2345
- RJ-07,3M-8888
- RJ 07 4M 2345
- RJ 07,4M 2933

and some invalid ones (with reason):

- RJ-07 3M 1234 (both (y) and (b) should be same).
- RJ-07 M3-1234 ((a) must ends with alphabet).
- rj-07 3M-123  (length of (c) must be 4).

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: @Timothy, Judging from the username: PHP.

Comment: You may need to clarify your conditions. I think (6) should read "b must be identical to y" and (5) "a must be one or two alphanumerics followed by an alpha". I'm gleaning this from your test data which doesn't quite gel with the conditions.

Comment: @paxdiablo i have edited my question according to your suggestion..sorry for bad english

Comment: May be your data set doesn't involve these but `KL-08 A 2319`, `KL-08 AB 8756` etc are valid vehicle numbers in India - not to mention the old numbering system where stuff like `KVK 2087` (basically something that matches `[A-Z]{3} \d{1,4}` are also valid).

Comment: @Amarghosh  You are right. then tell me which type of validation i have to apply?
min'm 2 alpha character and total length of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the regex... this should be safe in most/all langauges:

```
([a-z]{2}-\d{2}[ ,][a-z0-9]{1,2}[a-z]-\d{4})|([a-z]{2} \d{2}[ ,][a-z0-9]{1,2}[a-z] \d{4})
```

The reason why I have the regex repeated twice with an "or" in the middle is to meet your criteria that "both (y) and (b) should be same."

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to solve *every* problem with a regular expression, you can quite easily check it with code. All but number 5 are easy, so you could use:

```
^[A-Z]{2}[ \-][0-9]{2}[ ,][A-Z0-9]{2,3}[ \-][0-9]{4}$
```

then check characters 7 and 8 (and 9 if the total length is 14 rather than 13) for condition number 5. And also check the positions 3 and 7 are identical.

The code needed to check this old style is likely to be much more readable (and maintainable) than a regular expression to do the same thing.

---

On re-reading the question, there appears to be confusion in conditions 5 and 6. Condition 5 makes it sound like *any* of the two or three characters can be alpha whereas your second example indicates the *last* must be alpha.

Condition 6 use of the word similar indicates the *condition* is similar whereas your first example indicates the characters must be *identical*.

If the examples are correct, you can use:

```
^[A-Z]{2}([ \-])[0-9]{2}[ ,][A-Z0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]\1[0-9]{4}$
```

(adjusting if you need lower case as well) but I *still* maintain that well laid out non-regex code is more maintainable.

Comment: USING `.` can accept special character also..that's i don't want

Comment: @ILikePHP, that doesn't really matter since I'm suggesting the check for that (and condition 6) are separate from the regular expression. But I'll put them back in to keep you happy. That doesn't absolve you of the necessity to check those conditions outsise the scope of the regular expression however.

Comment: @ paxdiablo , yes you are right Regular expression really kills sometime, i have changed the idea to do it with RE

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$arr = array("RJ-14,NL-1234", "RJ-01,4M-5874", "RJ-07,14M-2345", "RJ 07,3M 2345", "RJ-07,3M-8888", "RJ 07 4M 2345", "RJ 07,4M 2933","RJ-07 3M 1234","RJ-07 M3-1234","rj-07 M3-123");

foreach($arr as $str) {
    if(preg_match('/[a-z]{2}( |-)\d{2}(?: |,)(?:[a-z\d]{1,2}[a-z])\1\d{4}/i',$str))
        print "$str\tYES\n";
    else
        print "$str\tNO\n";
}

?>
```

Output:

```
RJ-14,NL-1234   YES
RJ-01,4M-5874   YES
RJ-07,14M-2345  YES
RJ 07,3M 2345   YES
RJ-07,3M-8888   YES
RJ 07 4M 2345   YES
RJ 07,4M 2933   YES
RJ-07 3M 1234   NO
RJ-07 M3-1234   NO
rj-07 M3-123    NO
```