# Regular expression for Indian Vehicle Chassis and Engine Number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a regex for testing both Indian vehicle chassis number and engine numberes like **ME4KC093A98040032**,- Chassis No

**JF39E70321656** -Engine No

The regex that i'm written  for matching these is,

```
/^([A-z]{2}[A-z0-9]{5,16})$/
```

But this regex matching other strings like *JOHNDEO*, or the strings which contains underscores.

Can anyone suggest me an advanced regex pattern to over come the issues i'm facing by satisfying the below given points.

1. starts with Alpha bates(At least 2)

2.Only contains Alphanumerical

3.Restriction for special characters including underscore.

4.it should contain at least 2 alphabets  and numbers.

5.minimum of 7 numbers and maximum of 18 numbers.

**UPDATION:**

modified the regex like

```
/^([A-Za-z]{2}[A-z0-9]{5,16})$/
```

But this could only satisfy the condition 3.

Comment: `[A-z]` isn't the only problem. The interesting part is requiring 2+ letters and 2+ number, combined with the 7-18 char range limit. So I don't think this is a duplicate

Comment: @Wiktor: can  u just share the original question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923380/difference-between-regex-a-z-and-a-za-z Replace `[A-z]` with `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: but it can only solve the 'underscore' issue.

Comment: OK I can't close vote now I voted for reopen, but a better dupe is .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432416/regular-expression-for-indian-vehicle-number-in-javascript-and-php?rq=1

Comment: got the answer, **/^[A-z]{2}(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,18}$/** This regex will satisfy all my scenarios.